# Meaning of "lay down"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What does *lay down* mean?

> One of my closest friends is 24 and clears $100k welding stainless. No
>   degree, loves his job, but he worked his balls off to get there.
>
> Hardly unskilled labor. He chills in a warehouse all day listening to
>   music and **laying down** sick welds.

Comment: @Clark how do you put the quote box around the quotes?

Comment: I was sure this question was one inviting the snappy comeback “Only geese lay down, dear; the rest of us lie down.”  But alas, it was not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You "lay" a weld, that is just the verb used for the action.

Example:

> The general idea is to ***lay down a weld*** with little penetration, by keeping the amps low

https://www.gasweld.com.au/blogs/news/2011/Jan/6/mmawelding

Comment: This makes sense.  To "lay down" is to take action on the subject in some way.  Lay down wine, the law, music tracks, bunts, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that in this case the phrase "lay down sick welds" is definitely a slang form.

To "lay down" in this case is to perform an action, and I would say it suggests performing such action with style. This is often heard in reference to DJs who might "lay down fat tracks", or in other words: play cool music.

In the example sentence, I would also see "sick" as meaning cool.  This is common slang in Australia and parts of the USA. The register of the rest of the text is definitely colloquial, so that would fit.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "lay" or "lay down" is simply the verb used with the noun "weld". That is, when you join two pieces of metal together with a welding tool, you "lay a weld" or "lay down a weld".

BTW I think you mean "stick welds" and not "sick welds". "Stick welding" is a form of electric arc welding. "Sick welding" ... I guess that means doing it very badly. :-)

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted 'sick' as meaning "very good" in American slang.

Comment: I think it could also mean very good like cool and awesome like "That song is so sick!"

Comment: Yes, the "sick" as used here definitely means "very good" in slang; the use of "works his balls off" and "chills" indicates this is in a slang register.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "sick" as a slang term for "good", but then people are always coming up with new slang words to mean "good" or "bad". As there really is such a thing as a "stick weld", I suspect that is the intent, but without more context it's hard to say. Given that, as Mark B notes, the text includes several slang terms, it's possible that a slang usage is intended.